# whats the best way to stream data from kafka to oracle db

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, spring-kafka

I am trying to find a solution to stream data from Kafka directly to Oracle. Whats the best efficient solution for that.

Comment: Check out https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Answer (score 5):

Apache Kafka includes the Kafka Connect API. You can use this to stream data from Kafka to a database that supports JDBC, including Oracle.

The JDBC Connector is available as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/), or can be downloaded separately from [github](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc).

You can read about Kafka Connect in this blog series [1](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) / [2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/) / [3](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/), and there's a quickstart for the JDBC connector specifically [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html#quickstart).

Answer (score 1):

I may recommend using this set of libraries - [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-platform/). There is a module [Kafka Connect](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/), that allows creating scalable connectors to different sources and sinks.

Looks like the best connector for you is [JDBC Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html),  but also you may use some connector from community - see all available connectors [here](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/)

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Just for clarity - _Apache Kafka itself includes Kafka Connect_. 
Confluent Platform is a standalone distribution of Apache Kafka that includes the latest version of Apache Kafka, along with connectors, schema registry, and so on.

Comment: Kafka Connect is a framework for scalable and reliably streaming data between Apache Kafka and other data systems. Kafka Connect is a _part_ of Confluent Platform and developed by Confluent.

Comment: Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. Period. Source: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectapi

Comment: I'm not just being pedantic for the sake of it ;-) This matters, because people don't realise that if they have Apache Kafka, they have Kafka Connect. You can opt to use Confluent Platform as your Kafka distribution _if you want to_ but you don't have to.